# Mathematical notation around the world

Tags: soft-question, notation

What are the differences in mathematical notation around the world? I know that in some other countries they write 1,2 meaning 1.2, but what else can be confusing in an academic environment (when people are doing math on a board or on paper).

Comment: some guys (from England I guess) even write $1\cdot 2$ to mean $1.2$. strange!

Comment: @000 that can be quite confusing indeed, since $\cdot$ is (at least sometimes/somewhere) used as multiplication instead of $\times$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298957/why-do-certain-notations-differ-around-the-world

Comment: I think it is less probable to find differences in rather modern academic parts of mathematics, as there are limited widely used textbooks and scientific publication makes things more similar.

Comment: Actually the "British" centred decimal is like $1\!\cdot\!2$, with no spacing, which was easy to typeset but is laborious in the LaTeX era.

Comment: @hhsaffar Agreed, cultural diferences are likely to disappear as time passes, and it's what can observe in France for combinations and matrix transpose, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As seen [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11795/what-is-the-right-way-to-typeset-these-limits/11800#11800), in some countries a diagonal bar is used before the function to denote evaluation (not sure if it's in general or just in the integration case). That is:
$$
\int_{0}^1 x\,dx=\mathop{\Big/}\nolimits_{\hspace{-2mm}0}^{\hspace{1mm}1}\frac{x^2}{2}
$$
is used instead of what many users here would find to be the convention: 
$$
\int_{0}^1 x\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\mathop{\Big|}\nolimits_{0}^{1}.
$$

Then you also, of course, have different ways of denoting derivatives - Leibniz', Euler's, Newton's, etc...

Answer (score 4):

Long division has different notations in different countries.Wikipedia has examples: [Long division in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division)

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed that Anglo-Saxons use $\displaystyle{n\choose k}$ instead of $C_n^k$ for [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) or [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Also, repeated decimals are placed between (...) instead of being overlined, which helps avoid errors.

Comment: It is not just the Anglo-Saxons. By the way, these are not combinations, they just _count_ combinations. You don't call $n!$ a permutation either.

Comment: The left symbol is more or less standard notation, actually this is the first time I see the right symbol.

Comment: @ooo: QED. :-) In most European countries, it's pretty much the other way around. The symbol on the right is the standard, and the one on the left usually means a matrix or vector.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: But they **are** called combinations. :-) *Really*.

Comment: @Lucian I don't agree (under the assumption that Germany is a European country), though the distinction from a column vector is indeed hard.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It is. But so are France and Russia, along with other Slavic countries and Romania.

Answer (score 3):

Function composition, in the context of group theory (a permutation is a bijection from a set onto itself), can be written

$$(fg)(x)=f(g(x))$$

Or

$$(fg)(x)=g(f(x))$$

The latter seems to be (or have been) used by some anglo-saxon mathematicians, and appears in books by Burnside, and Passman.

---

Also, matrix transpose is denoted $^tA$ in France, while it seems to be $A^T$ mostly everywhere else. This can be confusing when you write a product: $AB^TA^{-1}$ is of course not the same as $AB^tA^{-1}$.

Comment: Interesting what you say about Burnside.  Btw the matrix transpose notation is used also in Fischer's Lineare Algebra, which is unfortunately a standard book in Germany (unfortunately because he does not even prove the existence of bases, the book is really terrible). But maybe this is just a coincidence as this guy basically invents his own notation.