# Multinomial=Permutations ? Binomial=Combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

I understand that Multinomial is a generalization of Binomial but Binomial is $n \choose k$
(or combinations)
and Multinomial is just like $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!} $ (which is Permutation)

Am I right?

Comment: with a bad joke, you are left. Actually, I did not get your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Am I right?*

[Apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets), but only when it comes to [partial permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_permutation) of [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). Note that other European languages use the word ‘permutation’ simply as a synonym for $n!$, whereas ‘partial’ ones are called ‘arrangements’, i.e., $P_n=n!$, $P_n^k=A_n^k=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, and $C_n^k=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\displaystyle{n\choose k}$, which can sometimes cause quite a great deal of [confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585929).